# Avoid warning from module in different folder with Pylance in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I have the following folder structure:

```
/mypythonproject
../modules
....mycustomfunctions.py
../script
....script.py
```

Inside the file `script.py` I declare the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../modules')
from mycustomfunctions import function_a
```

`script.py` work just fine, but Visual Studio Code shows a warning on this:

```
from mycustomfunctions import function_a
```

Telling me that:
*Import "mycustomfunctions" could not be resolved*

Is there something I can improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Pylance "prefers" the dot notation with `__init__.py`.
In my example, one should create a blank `__init__.py` file inside the `/modules` folder:

```
/mypythonproject
../modules
....__init__.py
....mycustomfunctions.py
../script
....script.py
```

And then, in `script.py`, import the module as follows:

```
from mypythonproject.modules.mycustomfunctions import function_a
```

This is not showing any warning in the editor and works as expected.